# User Input to Fetch data from API in Flutter

Tags: function, flutter, dart

I need to fetch data from an API by taking an User Input number. When an user types a number in the txt form field, it generates the fact for that number.

API I used is [NumbersApi](http://numbersapi.com/#random/trivia).

This is my function for fetching data -

```
String fact;
int number;

void userInputForTrivia() async {
    http.Response response;
    response = await http.get(Uri.http('numbersapi.com', '$number/trivia'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(response.body);
      setState(() {
        fact = response.body;
      });
    }
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    userInputForTrivia();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Following is the code for Text form filled-

```
AlertDialog(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
              title: Text('Enter your lucky number'),
              content: TextFormField(
                cursorColor: Colors.purple[400],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                controller: _textFieldController,
                autofocus: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter any number"),
              ),
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    userInputForTrivia();
                  },
                  child: Text("OK"),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.purple[400]),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
```

This is the txt widget-

```
Text(fact.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.purple[400],
                  )),
```

Whenever user presses a button an alert dialog box is popped up in which user needs to type a number to generate a fact for that number.

But whenever I type a number its not showing the fact, what am I missing?

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: looks like your number variable is not initialized

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan even if I initialized, it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

add `onChanged` method

```
TextFormField(
    //.... rest of the code ......
    onChanged: (value) {
      number = int.parse(value);
    },
   //.... rest of the code ......
  ),
```